# Why call it Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was the word “Trek” used in Star Trek?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/why-was-the-word-trek-used-in-star-trek)

When you think about it, the "Trek" part of "Star Trek" isn't all that appropriate. The Original Series revolved around exploration and resolving problems, not so much about trekking among the stars. Even by the time of First Contact, Cochrane's comment that the TNG crew was on "some kind of star trek" was forced (and not to mention tacky).

Did Gene Roddenberry ever comment on the choice for the name?

Comment: See (wikipedia)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek#Beginnings]. It talks of the conecpt of the show, as sold to the executives : a wagon train to the stars. So they probably wanted something star ---- and settled as trek which signified exploration etc.

Comment: Mea Culpa for the duplicate...

Comment: Space Crusaders sounded too religious